# Loop for constrained matrix calculation

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a random matrix in R, namely `M1` defined as follows

```
M1<-matrix(1:20,nrow=4,ncol=5)

> M1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

and I want to create a second one based on the following constrain. Each row must contain the row summation minus the previous point. Meaning element (1,1) = 45, (1,2)=44, (1,3)=39, etc. for each row. But I want to make it in a loop so every time someone changes the matrix (and it's dimension) the code to be able to calculate the corresponding matrix. The final matrix, called `M2` must be of that form

```
> M2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   44   39   30   17
[2,]   50   48   42   32   18
[3,]   55   52   45   34   19
[4,]   60   56   48   36   20
```

How can I define the loop in order to calculate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `rowCumsums` function in `matrixStats` which can be used

```
library(matrixStats)
ind <- ncol(M1):1
rowCumsums(M1[, ind])[, ind]
```

-output

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   44   39   30   17
[2,]   50   48   42   32   18
[3,]   55   52   45   34   19
[4,]   60   56   48   36   20
```

---

Or may use `revcumsum` from `spatstat.utils`

```
library(spatstat.utils)
t(apply(M1, 1, revcumsum))
```

-output

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   44   39   30   17
[2,]   50   48   42   32   18
[3,]   55   52   45   34   19
[4,]   60   56   48   36   20
```

Comment: Similar to your second approach: `t(apply(M1, 1, \(i) rev(cumsum(rev(i)))))`

Comment: Thank you, all three options seems to work perfectly, but may I ask, if the next matrix has for example 1 million columns, are these three approaches the same in terms of computation and time consumption?

Comment: @nickolakis you may get some speedup with `collapse` `library(collapse);dapply(M1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(x) revcumsum(x))`

Comment: Or with `fcumsum` `dapply(M1, MARGIN = 1, \(x) rev(fcumsum(rev(x))))`

Answer (score 2):

Some base R options

```
> rowSums(M1) - cbind(0, do.call(cbind, Reduce(`+`, as.data.frame(M1)[-ncol(M1)], accumulate = TRUE)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   44   39   30   17
[2,]   50   48   42   32   18
[3,]   55   52   45   34   19
[4,]   60   56   48   36   20
```

or

```
> t(apply(M1, 1, function(v) sum(v) - head(cumsum(c(0, v)), -1)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   45   44   39   30   17
[2,]   50   48   42   32   18
[3,]   55   52   45   34   19
[4,]   60   56   48   36   20
```